# How to display title for header text for header in first section iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Using method below of viewForHeaderInSection i try and display an image in table header section one , but i also want a heading text, using the method of heading title text i am able to display the heading for all sections but not section 1 , do i need to make some changes to heading view for section one to be able to display the heading  , if i were to remove the viewForHeaderInSection then the title for first header section also shows up

[image]

```
 let sectionTitle = ["Feedback", "Follow Us"]

 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    if section == 0 {
       headerTop.headerLogo.image = UIImage(named: "foodpin-logo")
       return headerTop.topView
    }
    return nil
 }
 
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return sectionTitle[section]
 }
```

[image]

Comment: if there is view ... it will not show title ...

Comment: you need to have title in View .... and remove `titleForHeaderInSection` method

Comment: @jawadAli - yes you are right , i am trying to make it work by adding some thing to the view it self, thanks

Comment: @jawadAli - with your suggestion i am able to get pretty much what i want , i updated the question with new view, can you please suggest how to add padding to one specific UILabel, i am using let padding = UIEdgeInsets(top: 2, left: 8, bottom: 2, right: 8), but do not know how to use it , thanks

Comment: @jawadAli, thanks problem solved , question updated with solution in end

Comment: You are welcome sir ... happy to help you

Comment: post your latest code as well ...

Comment: Do **NOT** post answer **Inside** the question. Consider converting it to an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a text label in your `headerTop` view and remove this function `override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int)`. So your code will be like this:

```
let sectionTitle = ["Feedback", "Follow Us"]

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    headerTop.headerLogo.image = (section == 0) ? UIImage(named: "foodpin-logo") : nil
    headerTop.yourHeaderTextLabel.text = sectionTitle[section]
    return headerTop.topView
}
```

Comment: i am getting a different view with sectionspage view being repeated i guess, i have updated the question with what i am getting now

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are looking for `tableHeaderView`! The issue is you are overriding the first section's header.

You may consider setting the `tableView`'s `tableHeaderView` for the `headerTop` instead. So all sections will have their titles as you expected.

```
tableView. tableHeaderView = headerTop
```

<sub>Also, if you want yout table's header to be sticky, there are bunch of tutorials for that.</sub>

Comment: thanks , i was guided by jawadAli to a similar solution